# loop Multiple column value amounts into debit and credit amount columns for a file in Python

Tags: python

I have multiple lines with ten columns, and three columns have amount value. I want to get the debit amount (+ value) and credit amount ( -Ve value) in the separate column in the same row? can you please help to write a logic for this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQaNT.png)

Comment: Must it be in python? Seem that Excel can do the trick

Comment: How large the files? Depending on it maybe use of pandas will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` package for this. More info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', names=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], header=None)

df['Debit for 3'] = df.apply(lambda row: 0 if row.c < 0 else row.c, axis=1)
df['Credit for 3'] = df.apply(lambda row: abs(row.c) if row.c < 0 else 0, axis=1) 

df['Debit for 4'] = df.apply(lambda row: 0 if row.d < 0 else row.d, axis=1)
df['Credit for 4'] = df.apply(lambda row: abs(row.d) if row.d < 0 else 0, axis=1) 

df['Debit for 5'] = df.apply(lambda row: 0 if row.e < 0 else row.e, axis=1)
df['Credit for 5'] = df.apply(lambda row: abs(row.e) if row.e < 0 else 0, axis=1) 

del df['c']
del df['d']
del df['e']

df.to_csv('your_results.csv')
```

---

Without the pandas package:

You can read the input CSV using CSV module in python.

initialize a new list with 0 values for each row.

Then, read the lines in file and loop through each row, if row[2] > 0 then insert at new_row[3] the abs(row[2]) value. If row[2] < 0 then insert at new_row[4] the abs(row[2]) value.

Repeat this for row[3] and row[4].

Finnally save your results in desired format.